# Search results error

Tags: php, search

I have a search field in the page. But if there is no matching results, it is throwing an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function show() on a non-object". I have attached the screenshot.

[image]

```
    <?php
       if ( isset($_REQUEST['usersearch']) && $_REQUEST['usersearch'] )
        printf( '<span class="subtitle">' . __('Search results for &#8220;%s&#8221;') .
   '</span>', esc_html( $_REQUEST['usersearch'] ) );
    ?>
```

But the error line is (228th line):-

```
    <div class='tablenav-pages'>
        <?php echo $p->show();  // Echo out the list of paging. ?>
    </div>
```

I need to remove the error on search result. It should simply show "No items found".

```
   function pager($items)
    {
   global $limit;
   global $p;
   global $searchTerm;
   global $pageLimit;

if($items > 0) {
    $p = new pagination;
    $p->items($items);
    $p->limit($pageLimit); // Limit entries per page
    $p->target("admin.php?page=User Control&usersearch=".$_REQUEST['usersearch']."&page-limit=".$_REQUEST['page-limit']);
    $p->currentPage($_GET[$p->paging]); // Gets and validates the current page
    $p->calculate(); // Calculates what to show
    $p->parameterName('paging');
    $p->adjacents(1); //No. of page away from the current page

    if(!isset($_GET['paging'])) {
        $p->page = 1;
    } else {
        $p->page = $_GET['paging'];
    }

    //Query for limit paging
    $limit = "LIMIT " . ($p->page - 1) * $p->limit  . ", " . $p->limit;

} else {
    echo "No Record Found";
}

}
```

Comment: You defined function show() but you're calling method show() on object $p, that must be defined in the class of that object.

Comment: by `$p->show()`, you are calling method `show` on object `$p`. Functions and methods are two different things. The error says that `$p` is not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting the error because your attempting to show a object that is undefined...use a statement to check...this is the premise.

```
   <div class='tablenav-pages'>    
   <? if(is_object($p)){echo $p->show();} ?>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($p) && is_object($p)){
    $p->show();
}
?>
```